# Why is String.valueOf(Blob) different that Blob.toString()?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, blob

I am working on a REST Service that will desiralize the request body and interpret it. My understanding was that calling `String.valueOf(objectInstance)` would just call `objectInstance.toString()`. However, I am observing different behavior.

**Working**

```
Blob requestBody = Blob.valueOf('[{"key":"value"}]');
List<Object> body = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(requestBody.toString());
```

**Not Working**

```
Blob requestBody = Blob.valueOf('[{"key":"value"}]');
List<Object> body = (List<Object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(String.valueOf(requestBody));
```

The above throws:

> Line: 11, Column: 1
>
> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('B' (code 66)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at input location [1,2]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`String.valueOf` returns `Blob[X]` for Blob values. I believe it does it this way because `System.debug` internally uses `String.valueOf`, and debugging a potentially non-Unicode stream into a Unicode String could break things. In other words, you can't reliably use `String.valueOf` unless you can also use it in `System.debug` and get the output you expect. `String.valueOf` is always safe to use on a Blob, but `Blob.toString` may result in an exception if the contents are not a Unicode String.

Let's go with some examples to show how other standard and custom objects behave:

```
String.valueOf(JSON.createParser('[]'));
// JSONParser:[delegate=common.apex.json.ApexJsonParser@7cde3f62]

String.valueOf(Crypto.generateAesKey(128));
// Blob[16]

String.valueOf([SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1]);
// (Account:{Id=001..., RecordTypeId=012...})

String.valueOf(new MyClassWithoutToString());
// or //
new MyClassWithoutToString().toString();
// MyClasswithoutTostring:[key1=value1, key2=value2]

String.valueOf(new MyClassWithToString());
// Hello There. I work correctly because I have an overridden toString.

String.valueOf(Date.today());    Date.today().format()
// 2016-02-10                    // 2/10/2016

Database.getQueryLocator([SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1])
// Database.QueryLocator[Query=SELECT Id FROM Account LIMIT 1]

String.valueOf(Database.setSavepoint());
// SavepointValue0

String.valueOf(new Component.MyCustomComponent());
// *** Crashes and produces no logs ***
```

As you can see, you can never *quite* be sure what you're going to get out of it, unless you're using one of the concrete types listed in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.200.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm), which is currently: Date, DateTime, Decimal, Integer, and Long.

It does say that it supports "Object" generically, but generally speaking, you'll get the "debug safe" version of a string if you do so, which means it will probably be the wrong value.

Comment: Whoa. This is fantastic to know. `puts` like behavior from String.valueOf for in page debug statements, yes please!