# How to view attachment content?

Tags: apex, attachment, blob

I would like to see the Attachment body in plain string, but cannot find out how.

For ex:

```
Attachment a = [SELECT Id, Name, Body, ContentType, ParentId FROM Attachment WHERE ParentId = 'a016A000000agQ6QAI'][0];
System.debug(String.valueOf(a.Body));
```

The output is:

> 12:28:14:022 USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|Blob[472]

But I need to see in a String the actual content of the attachment body.
How can I do it?

Comment: See also: [Why is String.valueOf(Blob) different that Blob.toString()?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/108763/2995)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the string value of a `Blob` using its `toString` method:

```
system.debug(a.Body.toString());
```

Comment: Works like charm, tried String.valueOf before your reply and didnt worked.

Answer (score 1):

Convert Blob to String:

```
System.debug(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(a.Body));
```