# How to read Body of Email

Tags: apex, javascript, salesforce1-app, emailfileattachment

I have emails attached in notes and attachments object.

When i try to read the body of Email i get Blob values suggest me ways to convert the blob into text.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `toString()` of Blob class.

**Example:**

```
String myString = 'StringToBlob';
Blob myBlob = Blob.valueof(myString);
System.assertEquals('StringToBlob', myBlob.toString());
```

Other option is by using `String.valueOf()` of String class but not suggested as this returns useless string like `Blob[X]` where X is the number of bytes in the blob.

There is [one answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/108766/20721) of sfdcfox which you might want to check before doing anything with blob. It says:

> Blob.toString may
>   result in an exception if the contents are not a Unicode String.

So use `toString()` with Try-Catch block. Check comments too for more details.

Comment: String.valueOf also won't get the content of the blob, but instead give a useless string like `Blob[X]`, where X is the number of bytes in the blob. For this case, I'd advise a try-catch block if the user isn't sure it's a valid string.

Comment: @sfdcfox ohh I didn't know that, so i suppose toString with Try-catch is better in this case, right?

Comment: Yes, I'd suggest taking that route in this case. The main purpose of String.valueOf is when you're trying to debug/log something.

Comment: @sfdcfox When i tried using try catch the field i am trying to populate is not getting updated

Comment: @Ajay can you provide your code? Also you can try debugging your code and provide the exception message which you are facing. Then probably we can help you better.

Comment: try { String attBody=b.toString(); acc.Body__c=att.Body; acclist.add(acc); } catch(Exception e) { System.debug(e.getMessage());}

Comment: @Ajay  `att.body`should be `attBody`. If this is not the case then please share exception message also which you are getting.

Comment: @Mr.Fordo it says status is success but unread..

Comment: @Ajay This doesn't seem like an exception message. Can you elaborate what you are doing?

Comment: @Mr.Fordo I have email attachment in attachment and notes object and i am trying to populate the body of email in a custom field present in account object but when i try to update it updates the body field of account object the field is left blank..

Comment: @Ajay in your code you didn't write `update accList;` statement. Please check if this is the case.

Comment: @Mr.Fordo i have that statement after catch. This is the exception Message  **BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string**

Comment: @Ajay  That is exactly what my answer describe. that if your blob is not a valid unicode string than it will throw exception. You can try [this code](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/25421/20721). Or maybe make your email body a valid unicode.